# Manage strings in Map

Tags: java, string, dictionary, arraylist

I'm already first time using Map on java. I'm creating a project on the console where I create Strings with this structure:

```
String = word1 word2 word3, code;  //This code is a number, can be the same as the 
                                   // Map's key.
```

Then, each time I create a String like this, I save it into a Map. After creating and saving into the map one or more Strings, I have to be able to show them in the console, or to delete one of them.

***The problem I'm getting is that when adding one String to the map, is overwriting the previous one.***

In the **main class** I work this way:

I add a String to the map:

```
musicmap.add(title, autor, format);
```

I list the items:

```
musicmap.list();
```

I delete one element from the map:

```
musicmap.delete(code);
```

***The methods add(), list() and delete() are methods defined in other class this way:***

```
Map<Integer, Music> musicMap= new HashMap<Integer, Music>();  //Music is a class 
                                             // where is defined a constructor with the
                                             // structure of the strings

public void add(String title, String autor, String format){
    int max = 0;
    for (Integer mapCode : musicMap.keySet()){
        if (mapCode > max){
            max = mapCode;
        }
    }
    int newCode = max++;
    Music musicItem = new Music(title, autor, format, newCode);
    musicMap.put(newCode, musicItem);
}

public void list(){
    for (Music item : musicMap.values()){
        System.out.println(item.toString());
    }
}

public void delete(int code){
    musicMap.remove(code);
}
```

The Music instance just calls to other class where is defined a constructor with the elements of the Music List (these are title, autor, format or type and code):

```
public Music(String title, String autor, String type, int code){
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setAutor(autor);
    this.setType(type);
    this.setCode(code);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line
`int newCode = max++;`
to
`int newCode = max + 1;`

Your key value is start with 1.

I hope this will help.

Edit :
In your code `newCode = max++` assignment is done before increment the `max` value, which create problem in getting you max key value by code `if (mapCode > max)` this condition is not execute because both have same value zero (0) every time.

Answer (score 2):

Change `int newCode = max++;` to `int newCode = max + 1;`

**OR**

Change `int newCode = max++;` to `int newCode = ++max;`

Currently all your keys are `0`. This is a hideous bug beacuse it seems right but the assignment here `int newCode = max++;` happens before the addition `max++`.

I think that you don't need a `Map` because you are simulating the behavior of an `ArrayList`. Change your implementation to something like this:

```
private List<Music> list = new ArrayList<Music>();

public void add(String title, String autor, String format){
    Music musicItem = new Music(title, autor, format, newCode);
    list.add(musicItem);
}
```

you will get your indexes that way. Avoid using the `++` and `--` operators in general.